# can we check timestamp in chatbot?

Tags: timestamp, chatbot, cypress

I am testing a chat-bot in which when a user send a message it shows first time stamp as sending then it changes to delivered at "delivery time" and if fails due to internet or any other reason it shows failed as timestamp. once the new message comes or reply comes the time stamp will disappear. Can anyone suggest how to do testing of this case in cypress. thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not exactly understand what you want to test. If you can not publish your chatbot code, you maybe can share your cypress code so we have more information.

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same issue and finally decided that cypress was not the right tool to test my chatbot.

In my case I had to test a chatbot in Facebook. But identifying the layers that composed the conversation bubbles was so complex that I gave up.

You could take a look to Botium (www.botium.at), which is basically an automated testing tool specific for chatbots.